# Quitar un Item de un ListBox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, listbox

Necesito eliminar un item de un `ListBox`, pero tengo dos forms, en el primero esta un `ListBox`y en el segundo también, pero necesito que cuando presione el botón eliminar se eliminen los primeros items que entraron como le puedo hacer?

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
    Form2.ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(Form2.ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
End Sub
```

Comment: Ya lo resolvi encontre la ayuda en otro lado, lo dejo aca:

Comment: ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1)
        Form2.ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(Form2.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eliminar el ultimo item que se envio a listbox se debe ejecutar el siguiente codigo:

```
   Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1)
    Form2.ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(Form2.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Si los Items están en las mismas posiciones se hace así:

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
    Form2.ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
End Sub

Si no es así que estén los elementos desordenados deberías de hacer-le una nueva función con la que eliminar ese elemento, pero siempre parte del elemento que se elimino en la primera lista, por tanto se utiliza el primer SelectedIndex ya que el segundo no esta seleccionado...